# change datetimepicker language is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `datetimepicker` and its working fine, but I want to translate the language to "pl". But its not working with none of the options below:

```
$( ".input-group.date" ).datetimepicker({
    format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
    autoclose: true,
    locale: 'pl'

});

$( ".input-group.date" ).datetimepicker({
    format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
    autoclose: true,
    language: 'pl'
});

$( ".input-group.date" ).datetimepicker({
    format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
    autoclose: true,
    language: 'pl-PL'
});
```

It appears always in "en". Do you know why is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) the method of setting the locale has changed. Use `$.datetimepicker.setLocale('pl');` before instantiation instead of setting an option value.

With an input of `<input class="input-group date" type="text">` you can instantiate like this:

```
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('pl');
$('.input-group.date').datetimepicker({
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    format: 'd.m.Y H:i'
});
```

Note that I had to use the `jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js` version of the plugin script file to avoid a [noted issue](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/517).

Comment: Thanks, its just add this "$.datetimepicker.setLocale('pl');" before $(".input-group.date....)"? Because like that the date picker stops working the the input is clicked the date picker dont appears.

Comment: Updated the answer - is it the same plugin because I see no "autoclose" option in the source code?

Comment: Thanks, but with "$.datetimepicker.setLocale('pl');" the code dont works. The date picker dont opens when the input is clicked.

Comment: If you copy the code above (the test input and script), remove any other script instantiations you may have and make sure you have the latest version of jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js below your jQuery script reference, it "should" hopefully work. It did on my machine. (also, check if you're using jQuery 3.0 or above - if so, reference a 2.0 version because there may be issues with the plugin with jQuery 3)

Comment: The input I have is like "<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
           <input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"
                                                       name="date" value="{{ old('date') }}"
                                                       class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" />
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            </div>". Do you know if there is some issue?

Comment: I'm guessing, but I reckon you've got some other script intercepting the click event on the input box - probably to set the value to the old date. You may well have a conflict of script handling. If you remove onkeydown="event.preventDefault()" from the input AND change value="{{ old('date') }}" to value="" AND remove data-provide="datepicker" see if it works. If it does, there is probably some kind of conflict that needs to be resolved by looking at the other script. With your input html, it still works on my machine - and I definitely haven't got a conflicting script.